# Java Circular Linked List

Tags: java, list, linked-list, circular-list

I have to create a method to eliminate numbers in a circular linked list
say we have values up to 9

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

and we want to continually remove every 4th integer going through, it would go as followed

```
5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3; //  4 is removed
9 1 2 3 5 6 7;   //  8 is removed
5 6 7 9 1 2;     //  3 is removed
1 2 5 6 7;       //  9 is removed
7 1 2 5;         //  6 is removed
7 1 2;           // 5 is removed
1 2;             // 7 is removed
1;               // 2 is removed
```

I have to create a move to traverse through the elements, and an eliminate to remove the element, but I can do that on my own. I am having a problem with my toString(); method, I am currently not returning any value.

```
class Digit{ 

    class DigitNode
    {
            public int num=0;           // Digit's position in line
            public DigitNode next=null; // Reference to next digit
            /**
            * Digit constructor, initializes number
            */
            public DigitNode(int number)
            {
                   //
                num = number;
                next = null;
            }
    }

    private int number;
    private DightNode current = null;   // Linked list of digits
    private DigitNode tail = null;  // Tracks end of list as it is constructed

    /**
     * constructs a circular linked list of
     * @param n DigitNodes, current is the first DigitNode and tail is the last DigitNode(next of tail is current)
     */

    public Digit(int n)
    {
        //
        number = n;
        current = null;
        tail = null;
     }

     /*
     * prints all Digits starting from current until tail
     */
     @Override
     public String toString()
     {
    //
         String strVal = "";
         DigitNode position = current;
         while (position != null) {
             strVal = strVal + position + " ";
             position = current.next;
         }
         return strVal;
     }
```

To me, I understand that I'm assigning position as the current value which should be `1`, thus while position is not `null`, `strVal` be the position `[1]` + `" "` for spacing. then I call position to be the next value which is `[2]`, and I continue until `null` which is after `9`. Thus `strVal` should be `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. But I'm not return anything unfortunately, I tried debugging, and placing some `System.out.prinln();` markers to see if I was returning anything, but I wasnt.

Comment: you need to have toString method in your DigitNode : public String toString { return "" + number; }

Comment: I have done so, but am still getting the same output. may I ask @kiruwka, what does implementing a toString() method in the DigitNode innerclass do?

Comment: please see my answer. Did you actually add any Nodes to your list and updated `current` before printing ?

Comment: No I did not, I knew I needed an add method to add the Node. but my instructor usually provides all the necessary methods, so I second doubted my judgment on an addmethod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to fill your `Digit` with `DigitNode`'s objects. I don't see the code which does that from snapshot you posted.
Presumably you could do this in constructor of `Digit`, or create a method `Digit`.add(`DigitNode` node). You need this, otherwise your `current` will always be null.

Next, you need to add toString in `DigitNode` as I said earlier in the comment, or you could change `Digit`.toString() to have :

```
strVal = strVal + position.num + " "; // note position.num to get the number
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no toString() in DigitNode so when you call

```
strVal = strVal + position + " ";
```

you are just appending to strVal whatever the default toString() method is for position, which is a DigitNode.  This is because adding an object to a String with '+' calls it's toString() to get something to add to the String (in this case strVal).

Comment: Thank you, this answered my earlier comment on why I needed a toString in my DigitNode.

Comment: If this answered your question please accept the answer. Like kiruwka says however, this might still not work as either you have not shown us code or it doesn't exists.

Comment: other than the givens I have provided, the remaining two methods is a move() and elimination().